# CURL installed but not working in RHEL7

Tags: linux

PHP -m 
**After running this command I get**

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
pspell
readline
recode
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

**And after checking curl version getting**
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.36 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets

**But when I checking running this code in a web browser**

```
echo 'Curl:', function_exists('curl_init')? 'Enabled: 'Disabled';
```

It gave the result that it was Disabled.

Comment: Please keep in mind that most of the time there are separate PHP configurations (including enabled modules) for CLI PHP and any other, like FPM, CGI and httpd (apache). Meaning that you may see enabled module while doing `php -m` from terminal (as a CLI), but your httpd server don't use CLI. I don't know what is your configuration, but make sure that php.ini and curl is enabled both in CLI and other places, depending on how you serve your PHP to httpd server.

Comment: If for example your httpd server or nginx is using cgi version of php you may also try to do `php-cgi -m` instead to find which modules are available/enabled.